# How to batch change .net target framework with powershell?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2022

This possibility does not exists in VS2022 so far.

I'm trying to batch change the target framework for dotnet projects of a solution with a powershell script, but I'm having unexpected errors and the change does not happen:

```
function ToColor($color) {
    process { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $color }
}
function GetProjects() {
    $dir = "C:\Users\username\repos\solution"
    $bins = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csproj -Recurse -Path $dir
    $count = ($bins | measure).count
    return $bins
}
function SetVersion($file, $ver) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
    $name = $file.BaseName
    $currentVersion = ([string]$xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework).Trim()
    if($ver -eq 5){
        $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework = "net5.0-windows"
    }
    if($ver -eq 6){
        $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework = "net6.0-windows"
    }
    if($ver -eq 7){
        $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework = "net7.0-windows"
    }
    $newv = ([string]$xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework).Trim()

    "Setting new version for: "
    "$file"
    "[$currentVersion -> $newv]" | tocolor "green"
    # $xml.Save($file)
}

foreach ($p in GetProjects) {
    SetVersion $p.fullname 6
}
```

And my projects look like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

But I get this error:

```
Setting new version for:
C:\Users\username\SolutionName\WpfDx12\WPFDX12.csproj
[net5.0-windows -> net5.0-windows]
The property 'TargetFramework' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\username\SolutionName\SetNetVersion.ps1:20 char:3
+         $xml.Project.PropertyGroup.TargetFramework = "net6.0-windows"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Eventually why could this property not be set ? How can I batch change the `TargetFramework` with powershell ?

Comment: `if($ver -eq 5){`... where does variable `$ver` come from?

Comment: @Theo second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a second `<PropertyGroup>` element in the csproj file which does not contain a `<TargetFramework>` element.  The line you're using to make the change does not target a specific element, but attempts to apply it to all elements with that document structure.  One of them throws because you're writing to a property that doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to make sure you're only modifying the PropertyGroup elements that contain a TargetFramework.  You can do this by filtering which nodes you are targeting.

```
    $node = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup | Where-Object { $_.TargetFramework }
    $currentVersion = ([string]$node.TargetFramework).Trim()

    if($ver -eq 5){
        $node.TargetFramework = "net5.0-windows"
    }
    if($ver -eq 6){
        $node.TargetFramework = "net6.0-windows"
    }
    if($ver -eq 7){
        $node.TargetFramework = "net7.0-windows"
    }
```

Technically, this still isn't targeting a single element in the document and will fail if there are multiple /Project/PropertyGroup/TargetFramework elements (because of how the values are aggregated in PS).  It's unlikely that you'll hit this within the context of csproj files however.